# By not complying with the offside rule, can it result in the incorrectness of a program?

Tags: f#

`F#` uses the offside rule for ensuring correct indentation. If this rule isn't followed can it result in the incorrectness of the program or is it purely a styling guide?

For example given the code for pattern matching:

```
let f x =   match x with 
   | 1 -> "pattern 1" 
   | 2 -> "pattern 2" 
            | _ -> "anything"
```

Note two of the lines are offside. I have ran the program by complying with the offside rule and not complying with it and I get the same output but just wanted another opinion.

Also what about for if statements?

```
let test x y =
  if x = y 
  then "equals"
  else "is greater than"

let x = test 1 2
printf "%s" x
```

Note the compiler does warn when the offside rule isn't not being complied with:

`warning FS0058: Possible incorrect indentation: this token is offside of context started at position (1:13). Try indenting this token further or using standard formatting conventions.`

The accepted answer will need to address the issue for both the pattern matching example and the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of Lightweight syntax is described in great detail in the F# spec, [section 15.1.4](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A604%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C69%2C526%2C0%5D) deals specifically with Offside lines. The description there is technical and concerned with lexical analysis for the F# parser implementation. Nonetheless, it has a couple of useful examples.

```
// The "|" markers in patterns must align.
// The first "|" should always be inserted.
let f () = 
    match 1+1 with
    | 2 -> printf "ok"
  | _ -> failwith "no!"   <--syntax error
```

whereas in your example a warning is generated instead. So you should be able to trust the compiled program to work as intended.

For `if/then/else/elif` clauses a special dispensation is given in 15.1.9, while their branches are falling under permitted undentations, 15.1.10, so that this is possible:

```
let test x y =
  if x = y 
    then 
    "equals"
  else "is greater than"
```